# Llenar un array con datos de la BD

Tags: php

Tengo un tema, estoy queriendo llenar datos (usuarios y permisos), que en la BD están separas por columnas, una de Usuarios y otra de Permisos. El tema que me interesa meterlos en un array. Muestro como lo tengo manualmente:

```
$users = ['Y1558','S8961', 'S4988', 'RY174', 'R1742', '18574','ry742a'];
```

Lo tengo así para que solo esos usuarios puedan acceder.

Lo que quiero hacer es, no tener que ir hasta el código para agregar a un nuevo usuario, sino cree un formulario, donde almaceno el usuario y permiso, y lo envió a `MySQL`. Ahora quiero extraer esos datos y meterlos en ese array, y que si agrego otro usuario, se cargue automáticamente en el array.

Intente esto, pero no logro sacarlo adelante:

```
 $users=[];
 $queryMySQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

 $respuestaMySQL = mysqli_query( $conn, $queryMySQL );

 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $respuestaMySQL ) )
 {
   $cant = sizeof($users);

   $users[$cant] = ($row[2]);

 }
```

Algún consejo?

Comment: No es necesario crear un array para validar si el usuario tiene permisos, basta con tener un formulario de login y en el momento de iniciar sesión, **validar si el usuario existe en la base de datos y si tiene los permisos necesarios**. O no es esto lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: La autenticación la hace con Active Directory, pero lo que hago es poner en un array los usuarios que si pueden acceder. Que son los que están en ese array. Entonces, para no tener que ir hasta el codigo para agregar otro usuario manualmente, cree otro formulario que almacena el usuario de AD en MySQL unicamente para hacerlo automatico el agregado en ese array

Comment: hice un ``echo`` para ver que imprime, y me trae todos los datos, pero todos unidos, tendria que ver como separarlos con ``' '``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He logrado hacerlo! tenia problemas con la conexión a MySQL por algún motivo no se conectaba.

y este es el código que hice, si es mejorable y alguien me indica lo aceptare con todo gusto.! pero en lo funcional, quedo ok!

```
$users = array();
$queryMySQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

$respuestaMySQL = mysqli_query( $conn, $queryMySQL );

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $respuestaMySQL ) )
{
   array_push($users, $row[2]);
 }
```